# Database read error in background thread

Tags: ios, swift, fmdb

My problem occurs when I'm trying to read my database in background thread. There are several crash messages e.g. "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION", who are referenced to the different code lines inside `FMDatabase.m` file, but an database error message is only one:

> 2018-04-04 09:16:17.166 MyAppName[821:12717] The FMDatabase  is currently in use.

This message error is with me all time, when I'm coding my project, in different ViewControllers, and to the this day I thought it's occured with my database instance/select function, but I find that the problem is occured by background thread. Here's portion of my code.

My databases instance:

```
class func getInstance() -> DBHelper {

    let documentsFolder = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    databasePath = (documentsFolder + "/myAppName.db") as NSString
    let filemgr = FileManager.default

    if !filemgr.fileExists(atPath: databasePath as String) {

        let contactDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)

        if (contactDB.open()) {

            /*** my instructions to create an database  ***/

            contactDB.close()

        }
    } else {

        //database exist, check version and update schema
        //version number numerated from 0 (default is 0)

        let version = sharedInstance.checkVersion()
        print("version: \(version)")

        //            switch version {
        //
        //            case 0:
        //
        //                print("case 0")
        //
        //                sharedInstance.setVersion(version: Int32(dbVersion))
        //                break
        //
        //            default:
        //
        //                break
        //
        //            }

    }

    if(sharedInstance.database == nil) {

        let documentsFolder = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
        databasePath = (documentsFolder + "/myAppName.db") as NSString

        sharedInstance.database = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)

    }

    return sharedInstance

}
```

My select function, which usually causes the problem:

```
func selectAllWhere(tableName:String, whereColumns:String) -> FMResultSet {

    if sharedInstance.database!.open() {

        do {

            let querySQL = "SELECT * FROM \(tableName) WHERE \(whereColumns)"

            let result = try self.database?.executeQuery(querySQL, values: [])

            return result!

        } catch {

            print("error = \(error.localizedDescription)")
            print("error = code: \(database?.lastErrorCode()) message: \(database?.lastErrorMessage())")

            return FMResultSet()
        }

    } else {

        return FMResultSet()

    }

}
```

And example of usage (custom calendar, which should display a number of events for every day in month, month are switched with `UIPageViewController`):

```
class  MonthlyCalendar: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

/*** collection functions and more ***/

let newInstance:DBHelper =  DBHelper.getInstance()

func setCalendarItems(month:Int) {

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    //DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default).async {
    //DispatchQueue.global().async(execute: {

        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let date = calendar.date(byAdding: .month, value: page, to: start!)
        let dayRange = calendar.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: date!)
        for currentMonthDay in 0..<dayRange!.count {

            var numEvents:Int = 0
            let eventForDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: currentMonthDay, to: date!)
            let day = calendar.component(.weekday, from: eventForDate!)
            let whereStatement = " \(db.columnEventDateStart) LIKE '%\(dateFormatter.string(from: eventForDate!))%'"
            let eventQuery = self.newInstance.selectAllWhere(tableName: db.tableEvents, whereColumns: whereStatement)
            while eventQuery.next() {

                numEvents = numEvents + 1

            }

/*** instructions, when I’m adding rows to array ***/

        }

        DispatchQueue.main.sync {

            self.collectionView?.reloadData()

        }
}
```

And here's a problem:

> DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async

My select query works properly, and app isn't crash when I'l remove this line (and code responsible for update of main thread a few lines below), but then my code works in main thread, and may lock/freeze it, when part of data in my table will be huge, and this is bad solution. The problem sounds like an background operations try to work in multiple threads, and when first thread will use my db instance, second thread return an exception on a database query, because this is already busy by first thread. If is it different, correct me. However, I tried to use different `DispatchQueues`, but all time this issue occurs. What is funny, first time, when I'll launch my ViewController, all required data is read properly (pages are load by default - 3 visible pages), and when I'll try to switch page left/right, a new content makes an crash. I can't find any solution of my problem. Above way to read data from FMDatabase is presented in more swift tutorals, who I read. Please, help.

Comment: Have you tried adding the DispatchQueue.main.sync call inside the DispatchQueue.global call? You may be executing the UI updates before the background task is finished. And I'm not sure, but I assume FMDB already executes the queries in a background queue, so you probably dont need that, just the main thread one.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I have `DispatchQueue.main.sync` inside `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async`, my pasted code may be a little illegible, this is placed after for loop, so this should update UI, as last instruction in `DispatchQueue.global`. Do you mean  should I use a completion task to make sure, my loops will finish work before UI will be updated?

Comment: What I mean is, you may not need to add your code inside a `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async` method because FMDB should do that automatically for you, so it's just a redundancy

Comment: Oh man, I didn't think that a solution will be so easy. Your first suggestion sounds like golden shoot. I've added an `DispatchGroup()` to check that, does my loop already finished, but I removed `Dispatch.main` too, and now just waiting outside background code block to continue work on main thread. Now this don't crash, and I hope that it will remain so Thank you.